# nvd3 pieChart legend issues for overlapping and column

Tags: d3.js, legend, nvd3.js

I make a pieChart by `var chart = nv.models.pieChart()`.

However, the length of legend is too long and I would like to make the legend a single line and want to display the text all without "...". Is there any option or where do I modify the size of width in css? Thanks

[image]

#### solution 1

I found a variable to set the length of legend to avoid truncate texts.
`chart.legend.maxKeyLength(50);` default value is 20.

Comment: So did you solve your problem Karl? If so add it as an answer and mark it as such, so other people know your `solution 1` worked. Best.

Comment: @Tom overlapping issue was fixed. But still I figure out for a column thing that I want to force. Thanks though.